# How to include a new JavaScript file to my Statamic application?

Tags: php, laravel, statamic

I am trying to include a new js file into my Statamic application. As per the Statamic documentation I changed the file **AppServiceProvider.php**

in the boot method I added

```
Statamic::script('App', 'newfile.js');
```

But it doesn't load the javascript file. Is there anything else I have to do to make the script working?

Comment: Are you trying to add the JS to the public site or the control panel? As far as I know, the above is for adding it to the control panel. Have you checked if it outputs a `<script>` tag for the file, in case the path to it is wrong?

Comment: I want to do it in a public site. Thanks

Comment: As the [documentation](https://statamic.dev/extending/control-panel#adding-css-and-js-assets) says, that is for adding it to the control panel (not the public site). I guess how to add it to the public site depends on the theme you're using?

Answer (score 1):

The `Statamic::script` code allows you to add JavaScript to Statamic's Control Panel, not onto your site, as explained in the [Statamic documentation](https://statamic.dev/extending/control-panel#adding-css-and-js-assets).

To add a JavaScript file to the front-end of your site, you will want to find the layout file in `resources/views` (possibly called `layout.antlers.html`).

Then you will want to add the JS file inside the `<head>` (or bottom of the `<body>` depending on what you need) of the layout, like so:

```html
<head>
    <script src="/js/new-file.js"></script>
</head>
```

Make sure you change `/js/new-file.js` to the path of your JS file.